# WSO2 rich client support

Tags: office365, wso2-identity-server

As far I know, wso2is doesn´t support Ecp, which is crucial fo rich client like Outlook. I am trying to complete login to Office365 mail box, with Outlook client and iPhone mail client.
Does anyone know how to achive this?

Thanks,

Comment: Office 365 supports SAML2 [1]. Can't you connect office365 with WSO2 IS with SAML2?  [2]
[1] http://blogs.office.com/2014/03/06/announcing-support-for-saml-2-0-federation-with-office-365/
[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Configuring+Single+Sign-On+with+SAML+2.0

Comment: I can achive connect only with passive profile authentication,not active. I need to use smartphones and rich client which are using active profile authentication.